# MVC: using BeginForm inside a custom HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code in a MVC view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <input type="text" name="id"/>
  ...
  ...
<% } %>
```

I want to **refactor** it to be reused. So I want to move this code into a custom **HtmlHelper**.

How do I use the `Html.BeginForm` in a helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not refactor it to a shared, partial view instead? Much easier than creating the helper method in code, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm already using a partial view, but this view renders the form in three different points. I don't want to duplicate code.

Comment: @Daniel -- then what about using a partial within the partial.  Both partial view and html helpers are just a way to generate an html snippet conveniently.  I don't see a real difference between `<%= Html.RenderPartial( "IDForm" ) %>` and `<%= Html.CustomIDForm() %>` except that the former will require less code to maintain and changing the partial can be done without recompiling/publishing the app.

Comment: Yes, maybe this is the way. Thanks.